# Javascript - Setting a datepicker to a specific date using a custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am able to add custom buttons to a date picker. The ones I want to add are buttons for Quarters, so Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

The thing I cant figure out is how to set a specific date when one of the buttons is pressed.

E.g. When Q1 is pressed it will set the date to March 31st. 
Right now Im just going to set it to the current year, ill add a year drop down or something later.

I tried the following but its not working:

```
$( "<button>", {
    text: "Q4",
    click: function(event) 
    {
        var inst = $.datepicker._curInst;
        var newDate = new Date();
        inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay = newDate.getDate();
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth = newDate.getMonth();
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear = newDate.getFullYear();
        //Code to clear your date field (text box, read only field etc.) I had to remove the line below and add custom code here
        $.datepicker._selectDate(event.target, $.datepicker._formatDate(inst, inst.currentDay, inst.currentMonth, inst.currentYear));
    }
}).appendTo( quarterContainer )
```

In this example I am just setting the current date, but i will be passing in a date when I get this working.

Comment: have you tried $('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, was easy to google though :)

```
$('#Q1').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018,31,03) );
})
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks. There was a slight tweak. I never mentioned it above but my code is in the beforeShow when instantiating the datepicker. So, instead of $('#datepicker') I just use $(input), where input is the parameter passed into the beforeShow function.